# Can you find the lower bounds and upper bounds for $|A|$ ....?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\theta_1, \theta_2,....,\theta_{13}$ be reals and let A be the average of the numbers $e^{i \theta_1}, e^{i\theta_2},....,e^{i \theta_{13}}$.  Can you find the lower bounds and upper bounds for $|A|$ as $\theta$'s vary over all real numbers?
An upper bound will be 1, by appealing with triangle inequality. What will be the lower bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lower bound will be $0$, which is atainable if you take $\theta_k = k\cdot \frac{2\pi}{13}$.

Take, for example, just two values of $\theta$ instead of $13$. If you take $\theta_1=\pi$ and $\theta_2=0$, then the exponents are $e^0=1$ and $e^{i\pi} = -1$. The average of $1$ and $-1$ is $0$.

For all $13$ values, the easiest way to prove that their average is $0$ is to show their sum is $0$. For this, consider that the $13$ values I proposed are $13$ distinct roots of the polynomial $p(x) = x^{13} + 1$. What do we know about the sum of the roots of a polynomial?

Comment: How it will happen? $e^z \neq 0$ for any $z$. Please make it clear..

Comment: @Priya See my edited answer.